# PHP Объеденить подмассивы

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть массив с ключем $arList['QWE'], как добавить туда значения массива из  $arList['ASD'] ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php

Comment: В гугле забанили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

примерно так

```
<?php
$arList['QWE'] = array_merge($arList['QWE'], $arList['ASD']);
//...
```